# XML value search with wild card character is possible in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xquery, sqlxml

In SQL Server, while reading an XML value, Do we have option of wildcard search in [], i.e. any same listed tag by the value like:

```
[COMMAND].value('(/ATTRIBUTE/ATTRIBUTEID)[*]','varchar(20)') 
(Note: [COMMAND].value('(/ATTRIBUTE/ATTRIBUTEID)[3]','varchar(20)') works)
```

```
 <ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTEID>A</ATTRIBUTEID>
      <ATTRIBUTEVALUE>a</ATTRIBUTEVALUE>
    </ATTRIBUTE>
    <ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTEID>B</ATTRIBUTEID>
      <ATTRIBUTEVALUE />
    </ATTRIBUTE>
    <ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTEID>C</ATTRIBUTEID>
      <ATTRIBUTEVALUE />
    </ATTRIBUTE>
  <ATTRIBUTE>
```

Using this in SQL where clause as

```
Where [COMMAND].value('(/ATTRIBUTE/ATTRIBUTEID)[*]','varchar(20)') like 'C"
```

but not worked.
getting

> Syntax error near ']'

Comment: The `[3]` isn't searching the XML for the number `3` it's an index operator returning the 3rd `/ATTRIBUTE/ATTRIBUTEID` element which, in this case, has contains the text `C`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
SELECT @X.value('(/ATTRIBUTE/ATTRIBUTEID)[text()[contains(.,"C")]][1]','varchar(20)')
```

To apply an XPath predicate that the `text()` contains the string `C`.

As you are using `value` and that expects a single result this uses `[1]` to get the first such result.

You may prefer `nodes` instead

```
SELECT n.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(20)')
FROM @X.nodes('/ATTRIBUTE/ATTRIBUTEID[text()[contains(.,"C")]]') n(n)
```

And if you wanted to get the whole Attribute element back as the context node...

```
SELECT n.value('(ATTRIBUTEID/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
       n.value('(ATTRIBUTEVALUE/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)')
FROM @X.nodes('/ATTRIBUTE[ATTRIBUTEID/text()[contains(.,"A")]]') n(n)
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bpETs0YZ)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of XML methods to retrieve all the `<ATTRIBUTEID>` values and then filter them using a `WHERE` clause. First we split XML into rows using .nodes(), extract  content with .value(), and narrow results using WHERE (e.g., LIKE 'C%').

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML = '
<ROOT>
    <ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTEID>A</ATTRIBUTEID>
        <ATTRIBUTEVALUE>a</ATTRIBUTEVALUE>
    </ATTRIBUTE>
    <ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTEID>B</ATTRIBUTEID>
        <ATTRIBUTEVALUE />
    </ATTRIBUTE>
    <ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTEID>C</ATTRIBUTEID>
        <ATTRIBUTEVALUE />
    </ATTRIBUTE>
</ROOT>
'
SELECT
    T.c.value('(./ATTRIBUTEID)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS ATTRIBUTEID,
    T.c.value('(./ATTRIBUTEVALUE)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS ATTRIBUTEVALUE
FROM
    @xmlData.nodes('/ROOT/ATTRIBUTE[./ATTRIBUTEID]') AS T(c)
WHERE
    T.c.value('.', 'varchar(20)') LIKE 'C%'
```